# Calling a method of a child component from a parent component using ViewChild()

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to call the method atualizarTImeLine() of home component from main component, I searched on the internet and got this possible solution

mainComponent.ts

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string;
  @ViewChild(HomeComponent) home: HomeComponent;

  constructor(private bd:Bd, private router:Router, private autenticacao:Autenticacao) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
    //   if(user!=null){
    //   this.email=user.email
    //   this.atualizarTimeLine()
    //   }
    // })
  }

  atualizarTimeLine(){
    console.log("we are on timeline of main")
    this.home.atualizarTimeLine();
    this.router.navigate(['/main/home'])
  }
}
```

MainComponent.html

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-white">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <a routerLink="/main/home">
        <img [src]="'/assets/logo-instagram-2.png'" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 2px;">

      <button class="button btn-add-post" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></button>

      <button [routerLink]="['./profile']" class="button btn-profile"><i class="far fa-user fa-2x"></i></button>

      <button class="button btn-signout" (click)="sair()"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-2x"></i></button>


  </div>
  </div>  
</nav>

<app-incluir-publicacao (atualizarTimeLine)="atualizarTimeLine()"></app-incluir-publicacao>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

HomeComponent.ts

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('publicacoes') public publicacoes:any
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }



  public atualizarTimeLine(){
    console.log("we are on timeline of home")
    this.publicacoes.atualizarTimeLine()
  }
}
```

app.routes

```
export const ROUTES:Routes=[
    {path:'', component:AcessoComponent},
    { path: "main", component: MainComponent, canActivate:[AutenticacaoGuard], children: [
        { path: "home",component:HomeComponent},
        { path: "profile",component:ProfileComponent}]
    }


]
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'atualizarTimeLine' of undefined
    at MainComponent.push../src/app/main/main.component.ts.MainComponent.atualizarTimeLine (main.component.ts:36)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MainComponent.html:21)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23106)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24176)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23903)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20555)
    at core.js:22045
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:13526)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)

Comment: There is no home component inside main component's template. Is it getting loaded through router-outlet?

Comment: yes, exactly...